# Renaming perl files with any extension

Tags: regex, linux, perl, glob

I would like to be able to rename perl files of different extensions as long as the name of the file is the same. For example,

`ExampleFile.txt` 
`ExampleFile.html` 
`FirstFile.txt`

I would like a Perl one-liner I can use on Linux to change a file containing string "ExampleFile" as name, regardless of its extension to "FinalFile", but not for any other file such as "FirstFile". I was looking into `rename` but I can't seem to figure out how to use this for any file extension.

Doing something like `rename "$findstring.*", "$replacestring.*";` doesn't seem to work because perl does not recognize `*` to represent any file extension.

Here is a sample code to work with that shows my issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $findstring = "ExampleFile";
my $replacestring = "FinalFile";

rename ("myDir/$findstring.*", "myDir/$replacestring.*");
```

Comment: **(1)** What OS?  The answer may be different on Windows than on Unix.

Comment: @cxw it's linux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a tool `rename`, which I believe comes with most systems (CentOS7 has it, for instance)

The man page is short with the synopsis and description

> **rename** [*options*] *expression* *replacement* *file*...
>
> **rename** will rename the specified files by replacing the first occurrence of *expression* in their name by *replacement*.

followed by one, not exactly basic but hopefully clear and helpful, example.

In your case

```
rename ExampleFile NewName ExampleFile.*
```

should be all you need.

---

Another way is to do this in Perl

```
perl -MFile::Basename -MFile::Copy=move -wE'
    for (@ARGV) {
        ($name, $path, $ext) = fileparse($_, qr/\.[^.]*/);
        say "Rename: $_  to  $path/NewName$ext";
        #move $_, "$path/NewName$ext" 
    }
' ExampleFile*
```

This will rename all `ExampleFile.*` to `NewName` with same extensions, once you uncomment the line with `move`.  As it stands it only prints what it would do, so that it can be tested thoroughly first.

It uses [File::Basename](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html)::`fileparse`  to find components of the filename for each of the files submitted on the command line, and then [File::Copy](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) to rename each file. There are other ways to parse filenames and other modules to call upon.

This is given as a command-line program for quick copy-paste testing; please cast it into a script, with due error checking. Then you can make a nice utility with better invocation using [Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html).

Comment: I tried rename but it does not work. I tried using perl `rename` by matching with regexp but I am not able to get it working still.

Comment: @sfr The `rename` I use is a binary in `/bin/rename` (on my CentOS7); there is at least one more utility out there with the same name -- see the man page of what you have.  The Perl code should work though; it does for me (but you _may_ need to tweak it, I can't fully test now)

Comment: @sfr Edited, so that Perl code (in the second part) now only prints as it stands, for easier testing.  Once it's all good uncomment the line with `#move...` to actually rename files

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @zdim's answer and want to add a possible clarification.  I think you may be confusing regex replacement with globbing.  *Globbing* gives you the list of filenames so you don't have to specify the extension.  Then you can use a *regex* to build the new name.  Using rename(1) is the easiest, but if you must have a one-liner, something like this might work on Perl 5.14+ —

```
perl -MFile::Glob -MFile::Copy -E 'move($_, s/^ExampleFile/FinalFile/r) foreach <ExampleFile.*>'
```

The `<...>` is the glob, and makes a list of the matching filenames.  Then separately, the `move(, s///)` does the renaming.

In the sample code in your question, you were using `.*` in a regex, but it appears you wanted that in a glob.  In @zdim's answer, the shell globs and Perl renames.

**Edit** within a script, the corresponding code should work (not tested):

```
use 5.014;
use File::Glob ':bsd_glob'; use File::Copy; 
move($_, s/^\Q$findstring/$replacestring/r) foreach bsd_glob("$findstring.*");
```

**Edit 2** without `File::Glob`:

```
use 5.014;
use File::Copy; 
move($_, s/^\Q$findstring/$replacestring/r) foreach <$findstring.*>;
```

The builtin `<foo>` operator, in list context, globs `foo` and returns a list of the matches.

Comment: My wording is incorrect. By perl one-liner, I was hoping it would be some way to use `rename` within the script because the patterns I want to replace are in-script variables. Is it possible to access to use the variable name from the script in the command line? (It seems by one-liner, I was suggesting perl from the command line)

Comment: @sfr Edited!  Yes, in Perl "one-liner" implies command line, as far as I know.

Comment: `"bsd_glob" is not defined` is the error I got. Unfortunately, I'm not able to install anything for perl either due to my work policy.  Is there anything else I can use besides bsd_glob? I did some research and couldn't seem to find a way around it except using a perl version that has it. i'm using (v5.14) I see there is `:glob` but doesn't seem to be allowed for iterating.

Comment: @sfr Don't have to use `File::Glob` -- it provides a `glob` better than the built-in one but it is by no means necessary.  The one-liner should work exactly the same, just drop `-MFile::Glob`. In the other snippet (for a script) remove `use File::Glob` statement and instead of `bsd_glob` use `glob`. And then watch out for names with spaces.

Comment: *Updated comment: It is doing the rename of the string in the file name but instead of showing something like `FinalFile.txt`, it is showing `FinalFile.*`

Comment: @sfr Did you put the `.*` in `$replacestring`?  I am going with your code in the question - `$findstring = 'ExampleFile'` and `$replacestring = 'FinalFile'`.

Comment: I did. I also put in an error statement and it says there is no such file or directory as the original one (which there is), and `'1' and '1' are identical (not copied) at script.pl line 23` where line 23 is the line containing the move.

Comment: Here is what I noticed. If the directory has a single file extension with that string such as "ExampleFile.*", it will change it to "FinalFile.txt". If it has two file extension types such as "ExampleFile.txt" and "ExampleFile.html" in the directory, it will change neither names of the files in the directory.

Comment: @sfr Would you please accept one of the answers to this question and ask a new question with a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you now have in your script?  I think we are past the limit of readability of the comments mechanism :) .  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**You can try applying the rename function directly**

Example

- rename("D:/GeeksforGeeks/GFG File.txt",
- "D:/GeeksforGeeks/GFG File 2.txt") ||
- die ( "Error in renaming" );

to the same code this might work

Comment: This specifies the extension type though. To do this I will have to go in and manually check all directories and do renames of strings for each file extension. I'm looking for something that will allow me to do the rename without knowing the extension.

Comment: **Oh I see** , [link](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=632437) check this out if it helps